# How do we get the coordinates of an UIImageView programmatically?

Tags: iphone, ipad, animation, uiimageview

I would like to get the coordinates of an UIImageView programmatically. How do I do this?

For example I have a square. I want to get the coordinates of all the corners. How must i proceed?

```
NSLog("%f", ImageView.frame.origin.x);
NSLog("%f", ImageView.frame.origin.y);
```

I get the topleft coordinate of the square.

I must say that the square (imageview) rotates and that's why I must get it's coordinates.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The coordinates in whose coordinate space?

Each UIView has its own coordinate space. You can refer to a view's size in its own coordinate space by asking for its `bounds`.

A view's size and position in its parent view is called its `frame`. In your example, you're asking for the image view's top left corner in its parent view's coordinate space.

If that's what you want to do, then try these:

```
frame.origin.x
frame.origin.y
frame.size.width
frame.size.height
```

By adding those together you can get any coordinate: for example, the x coordinate of the top right would be

```
frame.origin.x + frame.size.width
```