# How to get UIImage coordinates (x,y,width,height) in UIImageView in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage, coordinates

I want image coordinates in Uiimageview not UIImageview coordinates.

Because if i have a landscape mode image and i set the property of UIImageview contentmode aspectfit, It will show in portrait mode with white spaces and centered.

Please tell me how to get the x,y coordinate of images in UIImageView.

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3467911/how-do-we-get-the-coordinates-of-an-uiimageview-programmatically

Comment: @RachelGallen Thanks but that question is related with uiimageview coordinates.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9766394/get-exif-data-from-uiimage-uiimagepickercontroller/9890442#9890442 - it's better

Comment: Did you ever end up finding a solution?

Answer (score -1):

UIImage does not have a frame,Frame is for UIImageview

Comment: it has because it returns its width and height

img.size.width;

Comment: @NehaaSaxena `UIImage` does not have a `frame`; but it does have a `size` property.

Answer (score -1):

Try to create a `UIImage` from your image data or file, then use the size property to get a `CGSize` structure representing the image's dimensions. See [Apple reference doc.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Hope this helps you!

Comment: It only returns width and height

Comment: Did you see apple reference doc, there is no method or attribute to get x or y coordinates.The `UIImage` doesnot have `img.frame.origin.x;`. So you can't do it.

Comment: Yes I've seen that doc before. My problem is I've two images, one covers the whole view and other one overlay the first image. but when I changed the orientation the overlay which is actually on that image shows on the white space.. and the overlay image is movable(drag able). I want that if I'm changing an orientation the overlay shows at the same location where it shows in last orientation. Thanks